# MySQL: Adding innodb_log_file_size in my.cnf causes not starting MySQL service

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.1, database-tuning, parameter

I checked and found that `InnoDB` pluginis active.
By default, Innodb_log_file_size=5MB. As per the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_file_size), 
`its ideal values range from 1MB to 1/N-th of the size of the buffer pool, where N is the number of log files in the group.`

```
InnoDB_buffer_pool_size=1024MB and innodb_log_files_in_group=2
```

So, Value of `Innodb_log_file_size` should be 512MB.
To achieve this, I have written below line in `/etc/my.cnf` and tried to restart it.

```
innodb_log_file_size=512M
```

I am getting below error:
`Starting MySQL.Manager of pid-file quit without updating fi[FAILED]`

Please note that I have only two log files -one is for slow query log file and another is error log.

- Can anyone help me to find why there is a strange behavior and I am
  not able to edit `Innodb_log_file_size`?

Comment: If you had MySQL 5.6, the log files would get resized for you. Before 5.6, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

To change innodb_log_file_size do following

1. Stop MySQL gracefully. Check the error log and make sure it was "Normal shutdown", no crashes, no errors etc.
2. Move existing ib_logfile* to safe place. You will need them if you want to roll back
3. Change innodb_log_file_size in my.cnf to the new value
4. Start MySQL. InnoDB will notice there are no ib_logfile* and will create new ones